# Extract and search an unweighted multigraph from an undirected weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have an undirected weighted graph G(V,E) where the nodes are bus stops and the edges are the distances between the stops.

I've implemented a basic Dijkstra to search the shortest path (s, t) which works as expected.

The graph is a non time-dependent public transport network. Now, the problem starts because nodes can be serviced by 1..n different transport agencies. Each agency will have its own route passing through the nodes. But for the initial search, the graph is a simple undirected weighted graph.

When I have the shortest path, I need to get all possible routes that service all the nodes between (s, t). The criteria here is the minimum amount of changes.

So I was thinking that I could created a sub-graph H based on the nodes and edges returned by the first search. This sub-graph would have to be a multi-graph.

However, what will the edge weighting be? And I would need to return all `shortest paths` for this multigraph.

Is there an algorithm that fits this problem or should I roll out my own version which could be a recursive function?

Comment: It is possible that the shortest path the DA gives you does not contain the (s,t) path with the fewest changes - is that intentional?

Comment: It might be possible. The DA doesn't consider fewest changes but a custom weighting based on distance (but not actually distance). Currently my graph is not that big, but from tests I've done it looks like the shortest paths returned are valid. So I have to further work on these paths.

Comment: All possible routes is an $NP$ hard problem. You could try modifying Ford-Fulkerson. Another way would be to do a BFS and keep track of the nodes accessible from the current node, through the source.

Comment: For example, there might be a (relatively) high weight (s,t) path that is owned entirely by a single line, while the lowest weight path might involve two or more agencies.

Comment: I don't think that will be the case because the weighting function in DA is accurate enough.